# How to show that something is a logical consequence of propositions?

Tags: logic

I want to show that ¬p is a logical consequence of $(p\rightarrow q)$ and ¬q, but I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: The only row in which $p \to q$ and $\neg q$ are true is the fourth row; and in this, row, $\neg p$ is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We write $\phi \vDash \psi$ ($\psi$ is a logical consequence of $\phi$) if, for any interpretation I, $I(\phi)= V$ implies $I\psi = V$.
>
> Sait otherwise, any interpretation that satisfies $\phi$ satisfies also $\psi.$
>
> It is interresting to notice the following link:
>
> $A_0,...A_n\vDash B$ iff $A_0\wedge...\wedge A_n \rightarrow B$ is a tautology.

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccccc}
p & q   &\neg q & (p \rightarrow q) & \mathbf{\neg q \wedge(p \rightarrow q)} & \mathbf{\neg p} & \mathbf{\neg q \wedge(p \rightarrow q)\rightarrow\neg p}\\
\hline
T & T  & F & T & F & F & T\\
T & F  & T & F & F & F & T\\
F & T  & F & T & F & T & T\\
F & F  & T & T & T & T & T\\
\end{array}$$

$\mathbf{\neg q \wedge(p \rightarrow q)\rightarrow\neg p}$ is a tautology. Thus, $\mathbf{\neg q \wedge(p \rightarrow q)\vDash\neg p}$.

Hence, ¬p is a logical consequence of $(p\rightarrow q)$ and ¬q

Answer (score 1):

Consider the truth values of the expression $((p \wedge q) \wedge \neg q )\implies \neg p$. You will notice that the expression is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

it looks you try to show something that you can't
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
p & q & \neg p & \mathbf{(p \rightarrow q)} & ¬ q & \mathbf{(p \rightarrow q)} \land¬ q\\
\hline
T & T & F & \mathbf{T} & F & F\\
T & F & F & \mathbf{F} & T & F\\
F & T & T & \mathbf{T} & F & F\\
F & F & T & \mathbf{T} & T & T\\
\end{array}